# Migrate from MagentoGo to Magento Enterprise Edition

Tags: magento, e-commerce

We are setting up a new e-commerce site and while trying to figure out which platform to go with, I would like to know, is there way to migrate from MagentoGo to the Enterprise edition?

Cheers,
Iraklis

p.s. In case you want to contribute to our platform quest, feel free to write your thoughts on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673388/e-commerce-platform-for-start-up),

Answer (score 1):

Both editions should have support. I would ask Magento what options you have.

Having said that, you can probably migrate most of the product information using the API and/or DataFlow. That will require you to write a script that takes the information out of Go and then put it into Enterprise Edition.

Orders will probably be a more complicated beast. There is an API available for orders so you will probably need to use that. However, migrating payment information may be tricky as you will likely charge the customer again. I would probably change the payment method to Purchase Order and put the PO value as "Migrated Order".

However, the first thing I would do is talk to Magento about what kind of options you have. I have to imagine that they have created a method for people to migrate out of Go and into Enterprise. They should be based some somewhat the same code so maybe the database can be moved over as well.